# getInitalProps not working in nextjs page

Tags: javascript, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing, nextjs-storybook

I have created client side pages using getStaticProps on my Next js application. Now I am creating some server side pages on that using getInitialProps but this is not working , because I am using 'next export' in my package.json.Anyone  worked on  that type of issue ?

Showing error in console
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths: /content-publishing-system

I am using getInitialProps because my next version 8.9